# How to run a typescript function on (click) that's located in another class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular

I thought this would work, but apparently either my way of trying to implement it is impossible or I'm just doing something wrong.

```
<h1>Makes</h1>

<p *ngIf="!makes"><em>Loading...</em></p>

<table class='table' *ngIf="makes">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Id</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Abrv</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let make of makes">
  <td>{{ make.id }}</td>
  <td>{{ make.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ make.abrv }}</td>
  <td>
    <a [routerLink]="['/editMake/', make.id]" (click)="MakeSelected(make)">Edit</a> |
    <a [routerLink]="['/detailsMake/', make.id]">Details</a>|
    <a (click)="deleteMake(make.id)">Delete</a> |
  </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>

<a [routerLink]="['/createMake/']" >Create new</a>
```

See I have that html form, and the current problem is the Edit link. See it currently redirects you do /editMake/id, and then calls the function MakeSelected(make). But that MakeSelected function isn't located in the class where the form is binded to. It's located in the /editMake/ class.

It looks something like this

```
 MakeSelected(make: Makes)
 {
  this.CurrentId = make.Id;
  this.CurrentName = make.Name;
  this.CurrentAbrv = make.Abrv;
  }
```

So it should take in the make object and then equal it with local variables. Then those local variables are used to fill out the edit form with the information passed.

`<input name="Name"  ngDefaultControl type="text" [(ngModel)]="currentName"/>`

But the problem is I can't run the MakeSelected function in the /editMake/ class, as it runs only in the class it's binded to. Am I doing this correctly even? Is there a better alternative?

Comment: You can run `MakeSelected ` in the `ngOnInit` method of the `editMake` class

Comment: How do I pass in the object from the first form then?

Comment: With router params : you have the ID, you can now search the corresponding "make" in your dataset. You also have [resolvers](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data) if you want to only show the page with the data already loaded

Comment: @trichetriche could you please give any sort of example or documentation regarding the first thing you said, without using resolvers.

Comment: Sure, [here you go](https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route-in-action) ! (I advise you to read the whole documentation about routing, this will explains a lot of concepts to you)

Comment: Looks pretty complicated so far, but I think I understand the basis. I hope I will be able to integrate it into the project. Thank you!